# Align ImageView to center of a TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a Relative Layout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.38"
    android:background="@drawable/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text1color"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:background="@drawable/text2_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text2color"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <com.widgets.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The ImageView `@+id/myImage` needs to align to the center of `@+id/text2` TextView! Currently, it is aligning to the top of `@+id/text2` **and** is aligning to the layout's `parentBottom`. I don't want this hack.

Is there a way of aligning the `ImageView` to the `TextView`'s **center**?

Comment: Tried with your suggestions. Not able to solve. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case for a compound drawable (which is a best practice, to flatten your design).
The ImageView goes INSIDE the TextView text2, at its bottom:

Just add this to your text2 definition:

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/logo"
```

You can add some padding, too

```
android:drawablePadding="4dp"
```

The image is horizontally aligned to its container.
If the text grows vertically, the image will be pulled down (as the TextView grows).

To have the image left aligned and vertically centered, just change drawableTop with drawableLeft and you're done:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo"
```

Comment: Thanks. I add some more complexity to the question - It is a Custom ImageView! Now, how can I add this to `drawableLeft`?

Comment: I did that. No use. The layout looks bad. I added `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to `customImageView`. It helped. But the center alignment isn't happening. :(